# Magento2 :How To Use Form Key In Frontend Grid Using Ui Component

Tags: magento2, grid, frontend, action

When i try to perform massdelete action from frontend grid using uicomponent than it has throws **invalid form key** error.
Does anyone know how we can use form key in frontend grid ?

Comment: please Try to clear the cache from var/cache directory.
Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.

Comment: no man i already tried all these things but nothing happens same issue arise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add following code in your controller :

```
protected $request;
protected $formKey;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->request->setParam('form_key', $this->formKey->getFormKey());
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chirag you save my day , working great !!!

Comment: Doesn't this simply disable the form key validation instead of fixing the cause of the missing form key?